# Web based NX client?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

But I can't seem to find much about how the NX protocol actually works. I have heard it does something with sending X11 commands. But does this mean that the listening clients need to have an x server to run the actual commands and display them?

Basically, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to write an NX client for a web browser, because it sounds interesting to me. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. NX is essentially compressed X-Window protocol.

It's not a spec, but here is a general introduction to how it works: http://www.nomachine.com/documents/NX-XProtocolCompression.php

The client doesn't need to be an X-server, but it will probably need to be able to handle at least some subset of the X protocol.

If you are going to create an web based NX client, make sure you look at [noVNC](http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) which is a web based VNC/RFB client. Better yet, fork noVNC and add NX support. That way you don't have to waste time on input, events positioning, networking, etc.

Disclaimer: I am the creator of noVNC. Implementing other remote desktop protocols (NX, RDP, Spice) is on my long term todo list (part of the reason for the name). If you're serious, contact [me via github](http://github.com/kanaka) and I can give you some direction/thoughts and put you in touch with somebody else who has also expressed interest.

Comment: While noVNC is great I don't think it is suitable as a base for and NX client. NX'S strength results from compressing (and partly omitting) the X traffic. It expects an X server on the client side. So you'd have to implement a full X server in Javascript. Possible, but a hell of work. I don't think you will be able of using much infrastructure of noVNC for that.